# Create foreign key on foreign table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, postgresql-fdw

I need to link my table with another one which is in different database(say table `logs` in `device` db and table `accounts` in `user` db, both on same server). So using [Foreign Data Wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/postgres-fdw.html) I create a foreign table(I check it with running `select * from accounts;` in `device` db which works successfully).

But I could not create a foreign key to foreign table from `device` db still

```
CREATE TABLE public.logs
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('logs'::regclass),
  ...
  account_id bigint,
  ...

  CONSTRAINT logs_account_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (account_id)
      REFERENCES public.accounts (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION

)
```

The error message is

```
ERROR:  referenced relation "accounts" is not a table
********** Error **********

ERROR: referenced relation "accounts" is not a table
SQL state: 42809
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't create a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint that references a table in either a different database or through a foreign data wrapper. A foreign key must reference a **(base) table<sup>*</sup> in the same database** (a **base table**: not a view, not a foreign data wrapper table).

If you can change your design to have these 2 databases as 2 schemas in the same database then you can create the foreign keys without any problem.

---

<sup>*: there's also another restriction: a permanent table cannot reference a temporary table.</sup>

Comment: **[Discussion was moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80382/discussion-between-ypercube-and-bonje-fir)**

Comment: Hello @ypercube, We are creating the microservice arch in which I have an auth server that stores the info of the users and other microservices will have user_id in all the tables which will be FK and referenced to PK of the user table of auth service. On each REST call, I have to return data based on the user role *(for admin all, for a user based on used_id)*

Comment: What I have understood is I can replicate user table of auth service in other micro service's database using **fdw** and can perform select/SQL with the foreign table (in db2) but I cannot create FK which reference to PK of the original user table resides in auth service. **is it?**